# Why doesn't google maps api work with dynamic lat/long?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to place a custom marker on a map based on the address set by the user in CMS. By using that address I'd like to get lat/long for that area and, by using google maps api, place it on the correct spot. Here's my code:

```
  function getLatLong(address, callback){
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        callback (results[0].geometry.location.k + ',' + results[0].geometry.location.D);
      } else {
        return;
      }

    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    getLatLong("<?= $r['address'] ?>", function(addr){ 
      console.log(addr);
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          scrollwheel: false,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(addr)
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('footer-map'),
                                      mapOptions);

        var image = '<?= parseLink("images/map-marker.png") ?>';
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(addr);
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });

        console.log('loaded');
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    })
  });
```

So it returns `console.log(addr)` with the lat/long and if I copy that value in `center: new google.maps.LatLng(addr)` in stead of `addr`, everything works, but if I leave the `addr` there, it just doesn't load the map.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not very much sure why you keep initialize function in document.ready. It should ideally be outside like getLatLong. Secondly leaving addr must be copying lat lng as single parameter ex '81.32', '12.1' would be copied like '81.32, 12.1' which is why it's not working

Comment: @jsjunkie can you please post the correct synthax it should be then? Would be very thankful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no need to use `results[0].geometry.location.k + ',' + results[0].geometry.location.D` because `results[0].geometry.location` is itself a LatLng object
2. Here is the complete code that works:

```
<script>

    function getLatLong(address, callback){
        var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

        geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results[0].geometry.location);
                callback(results[0].geometry.location);} else{return;} });}


    $(document).ready(function(){
        getLatLong("indore", function(addr){ 
            console.log(addr);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: addr
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

            var myLatLng = addr;//new google.maps.LatLng(addr);
            var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map
            });

            console.log('loaded');})

    });</script></head>
```

3. I have removed that `"<?= $r['address'] ?>"` and marker image, please add it back again